# Send XML data from server to client in GWT RF setup

Tags: xml, gwt, xml-parsing, requestfactory

I have a web service which is called from the GWT server code. I get XML as a response from that web service. I want to pass that XML to the client side of javascript and render as is. How can we do that?

We use GWT 2.5 and RequestFactory.

Thanks a ton.

Comment: Is the client getting the XML from the ws-server, or is the client asking the gwt-server, and the gwt-server gets the XML from the final ws-server. In other words, are there two servers or one?

Answer (score 0):

RequestFactory is a special transport for a case when you work with some ORM (like Hibernate). In you case you work with webservice, not ORM. So you may some another remote call technique, for example GWT-RPC. Just prepare a RPC service with a method which return your XML as string. See [this page](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/tutorial/RPC) for more details about how to make RPC call.

**EDIT.** As pointed by @Andrea Boscolo nothing stops you from using RequestFactory in this case too (see his comment)

Comment: Just to say that you can very well use RF like an RPC service by using `ServiceLocator`s and/or `ValueProxy`s.